# error when pushing new project to github: https://https:

Tags: git, github

I am trying to add a new project to my github account. These are the steps I followed:

```
git init
touch readme.txt
git add .
git commit -m "added new project"
git remote add origin https://github.com/beahowel117/farm.git
git push -u origin master
```

but I keep getting after git init :

```
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/bethhowell/Projects/farm/.git/
```

even though if I go to my github the project isn't there

I continue on with the commands and then I get :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://https://github.com/beahowel117/farm.git/': Could not resolve host: https
```

I have even tried by starting over and creating an entirely new project and the same errors keep coming up.

Has anyone seen this? I can't find any help for it online.

Thank you!

Comment: The `https://https://github.com/beahowel117/farm.git` error message tells me that you are entering the `git remote` command incorrectly. Please show your _real code_ — copy and paste what you are _really_ saying to Git.

Comment: Also you should use ssh, not https with password.

Answer (score 0):

> but I keep getting after git init :
>
> ```
>    Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/bethhowell/Projects/farm/.git/
> ```

That is expected. If you have said `git init` in a certain folder already, then if you say it *again* you will see that message — correctly, because it's telling you, correctly, that you've already done this before.

> even though if I go to my github the project isn't there

That is expected. Saying `git init` locally has no effect whatever on GitHub remotely. However, at GitHub the repo *is* there (I know because I can see it); it is just empty because you have not pushed to it yet.

> I continue on with the commands and then I get :
>
> ```
> fatal: unable to access 'https://https://github.com/beahowel117/farm.git/': Could not resolve host: https
> ```

This suggests that you are entering the `git remote add` command incorrectly. But you have not shown us what you are really saying, so it's impossible to be more specific about what you are doing wrong. All you have shown us is:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/projectname.git
```

...which is obviously bogus.

Until you give the `git remote add` command correctly, you will not be able to `git push`, and until you `git push`, your repository commits will not be copied up to GitHub. So you're stuck until you get this command right.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for the response, I added in what I am entering for git remote to get the double https://https://

Comment: The repo is there becasue I went and created it after the fact to try and push that way and I didn't know how to remove. But then I tried to start over with a different project name and I got the same git remote error as well. I basically can't add anything to github from the cli

Comment: What does `git remote -vv` tell you?

Comment: I actually figured it out. I needed to remove the remote origin, reconfig and push again and it seemed to have worked.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case. `git init` leaves some cruft. I can see that you have now pushed successfully!